# Set an HTML document to page-break between each table in print mode without CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have an HTML document with 10 tables, and I want each one to appear on a separate page when printed.

I'm not using a CSS file, so need to include the command in the actual HTML of the document.

I've added this at the top of the document:

```
<head>
  <style>
    @media print
    {
      table {page-break-after:always}
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Which seems to work fine in Firefox, but in Chrome the whole `<style>` tag is ignored from the `<head>`.

If there's any better way to do it so that it works in Chrome as well, I'd really appreciate your advice.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `<style>` for print media?

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    ...
</style>
```